Open up my app from running background service?
I have an app that is running a background service on Android using Flutter and it's 'flutter_background_service' package. The functionality I want to achieve is to open up the app itself from that very background service. Any suggestions? I just can't seem to make it work :(
I tried using the 'installed_apps' package and it's 'startApp' function which starts an app by it's package name. Didn't work for me.
I had several different attempts using method channels, but no success either.

I think the only way to achieve that is by using notifications. When the user clicks on the notification of a background app, they can be directed to the app. I don't think it's possible to do something like this without using notifications, and as far as I know, Android does not have permissions that allow this action.

you should ask the questioner whether he want to open the app by the background service.
